# 30 minute timer that has normally closed circuit. It goes off when timer activated

Tags: power-supply

I need normally closed timer that I can set to turn lights off for 30 - 60 minutes then have them come back on. when timer expires.  This is a situation where we have a motion detection light that comes on as it should but clients wants to be able to disable (turn off light) for 30 to 60 minutes.  Don't want to disable the motion sensor as it would not be re-enabled.  With a timer they won't worry about motion sensor not working the next time, timer would re-set it.

Answer (score 2):

*Ignoring as off-topic the question of "find a part that works this way directly" I'll address the on-topic question of "how to do this with the usual timer that's on for 30-60 minutes and then goes off"*

Which is: connect the timer to the coil of a normally closed relay connected between the light and the motion sensor (or ahead of the motion sensor if the light and sensor are combined.)

Answer (score 0):

I have done the ladder diagram for you. If there is anything you are unable to understand, please let me know. I dont think conventional ladder diagram support is included in circuit lab, but still I have done what I thought could be discernible.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgNIaG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>